# placing favicon icon to all pages using controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have website which consists of lots of view. In this website layout is not used so I have to place the fav icon link to all views.

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/favicon.gif" type="image/gif">
```

Is there any way to includes this link to all views using controller actions so that I didn't need to place this link to all views?

Comment: DO you use different html pages for your views? you must have a template for you html, you must find the part where your html needs to be static or dynamic and by there , you can cut your html from head,body,foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create 'header.php' in your 'Views' folder

at there place your icon

**header.php**

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/favicon.gif" type="image/gif">
```

at your controller add this line

```
 $this->load->view('header);
```

Example

```
function page1() 
{
    $this->load->view('header'); 
    $this->load->view('page1');
}

function page2() 
{
    $this->load->view('header'); 
    $this->load->view('page2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template library like: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

From the user guide:

> Layouts in this library are very similar to layouts in Ruby on Rails
>   and other frameworks. **The basic idea is that most of your pages will
>   share the same header, footer, wrapping navigation, etc** *ed:[including favicon]* and only the
>   actual body of the page will change. Using this logic you can avoid
>   repeating yourself and having lots of similar HTML.